# Managing the result of NodeJS request

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a NodeJS server with a varity of calls

One gets all users:

```
export function findAll(req, res) {
    Users.findAll()
        .then(data => {
            res.send(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
           ...
        });
}
```

And one to get a user based on their id:

```
export function findOne(req, res) {
    const userId = req.params.id;
    Users.findByPk(userId)
        .then(data => {
            res.send(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
           ...
        });
}
```

Dealing with the result finding all users works fine and **users** gets updated with the result data using:

```
axios
  .get('https://.../api/users')
  .then (res => {
      this.users = res.data;
  })
```

But getting the user by ID does not work:

```
axios
  .get('https://.../api/users/' + id)
  .then (res => {
      this.users = res.data;
  })
```

From the docs I can see that data from **findAll** returns an array **Promise <Array< Model >>** but **findByPk** returns an object **Promise< Model >**. As such that I get this for all users:

```
[ { "id": 1, .... }, {"id": 2, .... } ]
```

But from the ID call (without the [ ] brackets) leading to an error:

```
{ "id": 1, .... }
```

So I have tried changing the findByPk method to:

```
const userId = req.params.id;
Users.findAll({where: {id : userId}})
```

but this still returns an object and not an array of 1.

Firstly why doesn't the findAll({where: {id : userId}}) call return an array as the all users call does? Secondly if this is just the way it is how do I update users with the object data? I have tried:

```
var self = this
axios
  .get('https://.../api/users/' + userId)
  .then (res => {
    Object.keys(res.data).forEach(function(key) {
      self.users[key] = res.data[key]
    })
  })
```

without success.

Comment: Your user-by-id endpoint is *supposed to* return a single user, not an array. If you still want to store them in an array for some reason, you should do  `axios.get('https://.../api/users/' + id).then (res => { this.users = [res.data]; })`.

Comment: @Bergi Great - your comment solves the problem thanks. But why does the Users.findAll({where: {id : userId}}) not return any array of 1? Users.findAll() does if there is only one record in the db.

Comment: No idea, it really should according to my understanding, but I don't use mongodb.

Comment: @Bergi Okie doke. Your answer has helped hugely. Actually it is postgresql. I don't use mongo either so no idea what that looks like. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, it looked like some mongoose schema model. If you're using postgres, how is that model created, what exactly is `User`? What library are you using?

Comment: Sequelize for the node side of things. users is the model server side and also the object in the resulting view. Vue.js and vuetify.

Comment: Are you using Mongoose library? or which ORM it is? Mongoose doesn't have findAll but can call `.find({_id: "your_id"})` to get the result

Comment: As I say I am sequelize ORM.